# Multi-query with binded values on PDO with sqlite throws an exception

Tags: php, mysql, sqlite, pdo

I am trying to run a multiple UPDATE statement with value binding on a PHP script with PDO and sqlite. Example:

```php
<?php

$db = new PDO('sqlite::memory:', '', '', [PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION]);

$sql = 'UPDATE tax SET rate = :rate0 where type = "download";';
$sql .= 'UPDATE tax SET rate = :rate1 where type = "product";';

$values = [
    ':rate0' => 0.1,
    ':rate1' => 0.2,
];

$statement = $db->prepare($sql);
$statement->execute($values);
```

This throws a `PDOException`:

```
PDOException : SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 25 bind or column index out of range
```

I'm curious: is this a limitation of PDO + sqlite? The same code works properly with MySQL driver.

**NOTE:** the same multi-statement query runs properly if don't bind the values and hardcode them in the query instead. Example:

```php
<?php

$db = new PDO('sqlite::memory:', '', '', [PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION]);

$sql = 'UPDATE tax SET rate = 0.1 where type = "download";';
$sql .= 'UPDATE tax SET rate = 0.2 where type = "product";';

$statement = $db->prepare($sql);
$statement->execute();
```

**EDIT:** thanks to @YourCommonSense, I realized that this second example doesn't work as I expected: it runs the first query and silently ignores the second one.

Comment: What field type is `rate`? Show the **CREATE** statement.

Comment: I would recommend running the queries separately instead of in one query.

Comment: As far as I am aware, PDO does not support Multiple Queries. Are you sure the bit you say works REALLY WORKS?

Comment: @MarkusZeller how does it matter?

Comment: _Small Point_ ___Well actually HUGE POINT___ `the same multi-statement query runs properly if don't bind the values and hardcode them` So its not even vaguely the same query!!

Comment: According to my [experiment](https://phpize.online/sql/mysql57/undefined/php/php8/bd7e7addbbedee3da372a22db774e812/), pdo_sqlite silently ignores the second query, only preparing and executing the first one

Comment: Note: your " the same multi-statement query" with hardcoded values DOESN'T run properly. only it doesn't return an error, but it doesn't work as intended either.

Comment: So in seems pdo_sqlite does not support multiple queries in query()/prepare(). The dupe is not overly reliable but well, the answer is the same. So you have to run these two queries one by one. Especially given that running them in one call won't make any difference.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. @YourCommonSense, you are right: the second example doesn't work as I expected, I updated my question accordingly.

Comment: Can I ask why you tagged this question [tag:mysql] if it's only about an issue with SQLite? For the record, MySQL does not support multi-query with `prepare()` either.

Comment: Another point: regardless of which database, I hardly ever encounter a case where using multi-query is necessary. Just run each query in its own separate prepare/execute.

Comment: @BillKarwin, I simply added that tag because I mentioned it in the description. And yes, I decided to just run each query separately :) This was not a real issue for me, but a question to try to solve a doubt.